# Passing arguments in React java script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, parameter-passing

I am trying to get arguments from function in React app on hooks. This is only an example. Does anyone know why (it doesn't matter witch function will be fired fireFavs() or fireFavs2()) it returns me always one step behind actual state and how can i fix this? I tried to write separate module or even separete hook but i couldn't make it well.

`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const CharacterDetails = ({ favs}) => {
  const favourites = useSelector(state => state.isFavouriteRedurec)
  let favIDs = favourites.favIDs

  function fireFavs() {
    console.log(favs);
  }
  function fireFavs2() {
    console.log(favIDs );
  }
return(
<>
        <IconButton
          aria`enter code here`-label="add to favorites"
          className={classes.actionPanel}
          onClick={() => {fireFavs2(); fireFavs() }}
        >
        </IconButton>
</>
 )
export default CharacterDetails;
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your code what you are trying to achieve, but what you describe sounds like it could be the expected behavior because `setState` is not synchronous ([see documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)). If you want to see the changes on the state as they happen, set your state in your functions and try to log within a `useEffect` instead (I see you already imported it but are not using it)

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(yourstate)
}, [yourstate])
```

Comment: Same problem here. I achived 1 step behind accual state. 
  let [inBook, setInBook] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    // setAddFav(favIDs)
    console.log(favIDs);
  }, [inBook])


onClick={() => {setIsFavourite(isFavourite + 1); fireFavs(); setInBook(!inBook) }}

Comment: here you go https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-snow-s4wv7?file=/src/App.js, you can check on the console below that it is logging at the same time